# MOSS 2010 Developer WorkStation

Tags: moss, sharepoint-2010

I am a MOSS developer.  Based on what I read so far about SharePoint 2010, I probably have to look around for another development workstation - 64 Bit with some beefy RAM, and most importantly to figure out which version of OS to install (Windows 2K8 R2, or Windows 7 Ultimate).

I need some feedbacks from others who have gone before me with hand-on experiences in setting up their workstations for this purpose. I welcome any suggestion on the realistic "baseline" on hardware/software requirements.

Comment: Since IIS won't run on Windows 7 out of the box, that's probably out, unless you want to run it in a virtual machine running Win2K8.

Comment: Robert - completely untrue.  Windows 7 will run IIS, just not on the default install; the component has to be added after install.  Windows 7 is positioned as a development platform for SharePoint 2010, and will likely become the preferred platform as time goes on.

Comment: Running 2010 on Windows 7 Enterprise on 4GB here .. its doable. Beats running inside a VM anyway.

Answer (score 3):

SharePoint 2010 runs quite well on Windows 7.  There are some manual steps in the installation, but [they're well documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869%28office.14%29.aspx).  So it's mostly a question of which OS you personally want to run.

I'm not sure yet what to make of the memory requirements.  The [recommendation for developer machines](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485%28office.14%29.aspx) is 4 GB, and I'm running with 6 GB, without problems.

Answer (score 1):

From my personal experience, running with 4GB of RAM on Windows 7 is **definitely** a bare minimum.  You're going to want at least 6, and ideally 8GB.

On another note, Windows 7 *Ultimate* isn't required; just Windows 7 Professional or better.

Answer (score 0):

My experience has been that 4GB of RAM just isn't enough. We are currently using 6GB with decent performance, but 8GB has been recommended to us. We are also using Windows Server 2008 R2.

If you use SQL, you will need to install CU5 as well.

Another thing you might want to think about, and I'd like to hear from others if they have any experience... is that your memory requirements may be less if you configure the minimum amount of service applications necessary for what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

We have a Virtual Machine created and we are using that on a 4GB RAM Windows 7 64 bit machine using the Sun Virtual Box. It seems ok for us and so far no probs. It is a good choice to give 3GB RAM dedicated to the Virtual Machine(Win 2K8/2K8 R2)